# gnutls_handshake() failed: Close notify - Docker and Only on one network

Tags: node.js, docker

Just came across a really odd problem.

I have been doing some work with Docker images and Dockerfile which included some bower install commands. It was all fine until today was the day I got a new broadband provider (Virgin Media in the UK) and all of a sudden i start getting errors whist trying to build images such as

```
bower ember#1.13.12                        ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/components/ember.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/components/ember.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Close notify

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/components/ember.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Close notify
```

I then tried by tethering to my mobile phone (4g) and it works perfectly fine. So there are many commands in the bower.json and it seems to randomly fail at any.

Even a simple command like cloning a repo from within the Dockerfile , fails when i connect to my new network but works with other networks.

Oddly enough if i use the git clone command on my Mac or even the bower install with the exact same repo it all works fine (with new network and 4G) however as soon as I try to run via Dockerfile I get the errors.

I have checked my router and cannot really see if it is a router issue what it could possibly be. The WIFI signal is 200Mbs so it surely can't be that.

Comment: I have a very similar issue - home broadband provider is Virgin Media in the UK, get a fatal error at a git clone step. Overcome by tethering to my mobile phone and using its Data instead of wi-fi. In my case the error is:

Comment: Error:
 => ERROR [10/19] RUN git clone https://github.com/<account>/<repository> /home/<repository>                  0.5s  
------  
 > [10/19] RUN git clone https://github.com/<account>/<repository> /home/<repository>:  
#14 0.430 Cloning into '/home/<repository>'...  
#14 0.528 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<account>/<repository>/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Close notify  
------  
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/<account>/<repository> /home/<repository>]: exit code: 128

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because of the protocal used by git. Just replace 'https' with 'http', it works for my case.

Comment: Could you add a snippet with the code from your answer?